# Anderson localization

Tags: anderson-localization

Numerically how we can show that states are localized for strong disorder? If I make a 3D plot of E vs IPR vs Disorder and show that for a particular value of disorder, where the IPR is approaching 1 starts giving localized states? Can anybody please brief me finite size scaling theory (how to do numerically) with formula and explanation?

Answer (score 1):

In numerical approaches to localization, there is many methods that you can use but surely the IPR is one of them. If the states are extended (e.g a plane wave) the IPR must scale with $1/N$ with $N$ the number of lattice points. However, if the state is localized in some radius $N_L$, the IPR must scale with $1/N$ until $N<N_L$ where it satures and becomes constant. In particular $N_L -> 0$ with increasing disorder and the wavefunction may be written as $\psi(r) = \delta(r-r0)$ giving IPR = 1.

Instead of looking at the value of the IPR, you shoul look at its behavior with the system size.

Anderson's scaling theory is a renormalization approach. For 1D and 2D any amount of disorder localizes all the states. However, for 3D, there is a phase transition at $W_C \sim 16.1$, where for $W<W_C$ there is a mobility edge, a specific energy that separates localized from extended states. For $W>W_C$ all the states become localized.

Comment: I agree that IPR is the best bet, and the finite size scaling analysis is part of it. One could also try to show vanishing conductivity via linear response / Kubo formula with current-current correlations, but this is harder. Or, try to fit a single-particle eigenstate to an exponential function $\exp(|x-x_0|/\xi)$ localized to some site $x_0$, but this is much harder. There may be analyses using two-point concurrences or temporal autocorrelations as well. But I think IPR is nicest.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. But in IPR technique how one can get the exact critical value of disorder, (W_c) (which as u mentioned 16.1 for 3D case) which seprates localized and delocalized states?

Comment: With IPR, in some cases, it is difficult to extract the exact critical disorder.  A possible way is to obtain the average IPR for many disorder configurations, for different system sizes, as a function of disorder strength. Then for each value of W, obtain the fit IPR = N^-a, and plot a(W). There has to be a difference.